# Msg 8152, Level 16, State 4, Line 1 String or binary data would be truncated These are not real People or SSN's

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting an error:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
>   String or binary data would be truncated

What am I doing wrong?

```
INSERT INTO Person(PID, First_Name, Middle_I, Last_Name, Birth_Date, SSN, Gender, Student_Active, Staff_Active, Mod_date)
VALUES (1, 'Mohammad', 'A', 'Ratliff', '1957-06-04', '346-05-9842', 'M', 'Yes', 'No', '19563-06-04'),
       (2, 'Lidia', 'B', 'Knapp', '1955-08-13', '758-10-7115', 'F', 'Yes', 'No', '19542-07-02'),
       (3, 'Alexandre', 'C', 'Wright', '1989-01-06', '567-30-3117', 'M', 'Yes', 'No', '19564-02-1'),
       (4, 'Cortez ', 'D', 'Payne', '1983-10-08', '513-30-0449', 'M', 'No', 'No', '19532-06-04'),
       (5, 'Sherman', 'E', 'Yang', '1955-12-29', '246-97-0792', 'M', 'Yes', 'Yes', '19547-06-04'),
       (6, 'Remington', 'F', 'Montoya', '1989-01-22', '672-20-4607', 'M', 'Yes', 'No', '19554-02-05'),
       (7, 'Yessenia', 'G', 'Petty', '1967-12-03', '508-78-9337', 'F', 'Yes', 'No', '19547-01-01'),
       (8, 'Yvette', 'H', 'Mcgowan', '1979-10-29', '019-88-7329', 'F', 'No', 'No', '19123-04-09'),
       (9, 'Hugh', 'I', 'Cooke', '1950-03-12', '699-14-9893', 'M', 'Yes', 'No', '19563-06-04'),
       (10, 'Curtis', 'J', 'Mooney', '1979-09-17', '193-20-2358', 'M', 'No', 'No', '19551-02-07'),
       (11, 'Desiree', 'K', 'Ayers', '1981-10-16', '256-84-1903', 'F', 'Yes', 'Yes', '19533-07-08');
```

Here is my table:

[image]

Comment: `'19542-07-02'` doesn't look like a valid date to me.

Comment: You best hope that those aren't real names and SSNs you've posted.

Comment: They're fake generated profiles just making a database for a class

Comment: sorry should have put that in title

Comment: ive changed the dates but am still getting the same line 1 error

Comment: `'Yes'` and `'No'` don't look like valid bit values.

Comment: `SSN` is eleven characters with the two dashes. Your field only allows for ten characters.

Comment: you  have posted the inserts statements,if you could have posted table schema as well as DDL statements,it would help  to easily repro this,please consider adding this step going forward.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of observations:

1. The thing that's probably causing your problem is that SSN (with dashes) is 11 characters, not 10. I think you already figured that out, just stating it here for completness' sake
2. Accounting for length correctness, why is SSN of type nvarchar(11)? It's always exactly the same length and is composed of only digits and dashes. A better type would be char(11) (i.e. just ascii, fixed width)
3. First_Name and Last_Name are nvarchar (appropriate since people come from all over the place), but Middle_I is char(1). Presumably, middle names can have exotic characters in them as well; I'd suggest moving that to nchar(1).
4. While I admit that gender is a tricky issue these days (i.e. we have more than the traditional M/F binary classification), I doubt someone is going to be specifying `∰` for their gender (though I do support alternative lifestyles). Figure out what the list of things that you want to support is and pick an appropriate data type.
5. Unless PID is coming from some external system that generates is, it should be an identity column (or generated with a sequence). Either way, don't make your application come up with a value.

Answer (score -1):

@Levi Shields- The value for the bit field needs to be 1 or 0.... Did you try using 1 for true/yes and 0 instead of a false /no ? 
Can you give that a shot ?

Comment: that was part of the issue I also had to drop the table and remake it.Thanks everyone for the help It works now.